# wordpress сайт в PHP скрипте $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] выдаёт разные значения хотя захожу с одного и того же устройства и браузера

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток!

сайт выложил уже на хостинг.
с помощью $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] принимается решение какую версию сайта показывать мобильную или десктопную.

сначала вроде работает нормально, потом ни с того ни с сего на мобильном начинает показывать десктоп версию или наоборот на десктоп мобильную, хотя открывают его с одних и тех же устройств и браузеров.

вот код

```
$mobile =false;
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$bberry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$webos = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
if ($android || $bberry || $iphone || $ipod || $webos== true) 
{ 
$mobile =true;
}
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


if($mobile)
    {
        require "enMob.php";
    }
    else
    {
        require "en.php";
    }
```

P.S.
проблема точно не в функции strpos. у меня есть строка echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; и я вижу что там отображается windows вместо андроида. или андроид вместо windows. то есть проблема в том что $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] почему-то содержит неверную информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
if (isMobile()) {
    require 'enMob.php';
} else {
    require 'en.php';
}

function isMobile() {
    $userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (stripos($userAgent, 'mobile') !== false) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php) может возвращать и `0`, и логическое `false`. Поэтому нужно делать чуть сложнее проверку, нежели это сделано у Вас. Вот пример из документации:

> Пример #1 Использование ===

```
<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Заметьте, что используется ===.  Использование == не даст верного
// результата, так как 'a' находится в нулевой позиции.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "Строка '$findme' не найдена в строке '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "Строка '$findme' найдена в строке '$mystring'";
    echo " в позиции $pos";
}
?>
```

В Вашем случае, возможно, тоже происходит подобное срабатывание, когда искомое имя в позиции `0`. Попробуйте заменить ваше условие на следующее или же из соседнего ответа, но конкретно с Вашими значениями:

```
function isMobile()
{
    $types = ["Android","BlackBerry","iPhone","iPod","webOS"];
    $userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    foreach($types as $type)
    {
        if (stripos($userAgent, $type) !== false)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if (isMobile())
    require 'enMob.php';
else
    require 'en.php';
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
проблема точно не в функции strpos.

у меня есть строка echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

и я вижу что там отображается windows вместо андроида.
или андроид вместо windows.

то есть проблема в том что $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] почему-то содержит неверную информацию.

Comment: @SevaSid12 Хм... `Все элементы массива $_SERVER, ключи которых начинаются с «HTTP_», взяты из заголовков HTTP-запросов, и им нельзя доверять.` Цитата  первого комментария из документации по теме [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php). Вероятно при перезагрузках страниц что-то меняется в настройках...

Comment: ок, так а где же мне взять актуальную информацию? как точно понять у юзера мобильное устройство или десктоп?